# Switching between alias names and table names using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, table, alias

Whenever I add standalone tables from my file geodatabase to an ArcGIS Pro map, the alias names are displayed instead of the table names. I want to view these tables using only their table names. Furthermore, I could not find any ArcPy functions that can automate these changes nor could I find any geoprocessing tools.

Is there any way to change all of the table names in my ArcGIS Pro project without having to manually go through each one?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [AlterAliasName](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/alteraliasname.htm).  Without testing it looks like you could iterate a list of tables to make all table aliases the same as their names.

Comment: Unfortunately, that function alters the alias name of the table stored in my file geodatabase but not how its viewed in an ArcGIS Pro map.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way to prevent ArcGIS Pro from using the alias of a file geodatabase table as the standalone table name used when it is added to a map.

Consequently, I think you will need to write a script that iterates through each table in your map (Map objects have a listTables method), and then uses the dataSource property of each Table object returned to lookup its name property, so that you can change the table name in your map to that.

If you are not comfortable coding then you could submit an ArcGIS Idea to have ArcGIS Pro provide an option to ignore table aliases when adding tables to maps.

Comment: I agree with @PolyGeo, there is currently no option to turn off layer/table name alias as you add the dataset to a map and default to the data source name. This would be a good Idea to suggest on geonet.